# KeyError Filling Defaultdict Python

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am attempting to fill a default dictionary with csv data, and I am getting a key error

```
for i in range(0,1):

    #https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
    result = co.defaultdict(list)
    with open(os.path.join(inputdir,tablelist[i])) as f:

        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
        read = csv.DictReader(f)

        for line in read:
            for j in range(1,len(csv_headings)):
  error here--->result[line[csv_headings[0]]].append(line[csv_headings[j]])
```

for csv data

```
API,CNTYNM,PRMT,
4700100002,Barbour,2,
4700100003,Barbour,3,
4700100004,Barbour,4,
```

the key error is for API which means to me that something with dictreader is not working as expected can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `fieldnames` argument to [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). If you modify your code to pass `csv_haedings` to `DictReader` it will work (hopefully as expected):

```
for i in range(0,1):

    #https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
    result = co.defaultdict(list)
    with open(os.path.join(inputdir,tablelist[i])) as f:

        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
        read = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=csv_headings)

        for line in read:
            for j in range(1,len(csv_headings)):
                result[line[csv_headings[0]]].append(line[csv_headings[j]])
```

Comment: oh man, I did not see that for about half an hour now. Thanks, I didnt realize fieldnames had to be passed to dictreader, however it does make snesne